# Alpine Linux - sed - What Is The Equivalent Of -z or --null-data Switch When Using Alpine sed Utility?

Tags: sed, alpine-linux

In a previous project I used the sed utility to replace newlines with NUL characters for compatibility with the API for adding a release note on the CI server.

```sh
sed -zE 's/\r\n|\n/\\n/g' < CHANGELOG.md
```

However, in a different project I am using an alpine based docker image (`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-alpine`) and the `-z` or `--null-data` image is unrecognised on alpine linux when using the `sed` utility.

How do I achieve the equivalent of the `-z` or `--null-data` with Alpine Linux `sed` utility?

Comment: Try running `apk add --update sed` first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What Is The Equivalent Of -z or --null-data Switch When Using Alpine sed Utility?

There is no equivalent.

> How do I achieve the equivalent of the -z or --null-data with Alpine Linux sed utility?

Instead of using busybox sed, install GNU sed.

```
/ # sed --help
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.
/ # apk add sed
...
/ # sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.8
```

> I used the sed utility to replace newlines with NUL

Use `tr`, it's a tool created to "translate or delete characters".

```
tr '\n' '\0'
```

> ```
> sed -zE 's/\r\n|\n/\\n/g'
> ```

If you want to remote `\r`, no need to use zero separated streams. Just remove `\r` character from the actual end of line, why match the newline, if `sed` already works on lines.

```
sed 's/\r$//'
```

but really, again, to remove characters use `tr`:

```
tr -d '\r'
```